# Redefine question label in examdesign

Tags: examdesign

In the `examdesign` document class I can't figure out how to redefine the question label. Its default configuration is something like `\arabic{questionnumber}.` (mind the dot). This gets confusing sometimes as the numeral of the question (and its dot) get mistaken as part of the question.

Is there a way to redefine the question label?

Edit: my code looks something like:

```
\documentclass{examdesign}
\class{Some exam} % Necessary to compile without errors.

\begin{document}
\begin{multiplechoice}
\begin{question}
What is the correct answer?
\choice{This is not.}
\choice[!]{This is.}
\choice{This is not.}
\end{question}
\end{multiplechoice}
\end{document}
```

To clarify, I want it to print something other than `1.` (suggestions accepted).

Comment: Can you add a small example of code?

Comment: OK, edited my question.

Comment: So you want it to print something other than `1.`? If so, what do you want? How is it mistaken as part of the question?

Comment: Anything really... I just concentrated on asking how to modify the `1. `. In fact, I'm open to suggestions as to what would be a good choice that differentiates itself from the question. Maybe adding more horizontal space? Using something like `1.-`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number is printed using the standard `\labelenumi` command, so it's sufficient to redefine it:

```
\documentclass{examdesign}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi. --}
\makeatother


\class{Some exam} % Necessary to compile without errors.

\begin{document}
\begin{multiplechoice}
\begin{question}
What is the correct answer?                
\choice{This is not.}
\choice[!]{This is.}
\choice{This is not.}
\end{question}
\end{multiplechoice}
\end{document}
```

[image]